# "zip file closed" when deploying Spring Boot application to AWS/railway.app/docker

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, deployment

I face that problem everytime i want to deploy my Spring Boot application which opens webserver at localhost:8080. It works at localhost.

> 2023-01-10T12:40:42.326Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
> 2023-01-10T12:40:42.326Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
> 2023-01-10T12:40:42.605Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:11.0.0-M1]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:252) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:486) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at com.example.RappersInfo.demo.RappersInfo.main(RappersInfo.java:19) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:11.0.0-M1]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> 37 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:831) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1057) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1100) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManEntry(JarFile.java:937) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:1000) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(JarFile.java:389) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.(JarFileUrlJar.java:68) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:11.0.0-M1]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:41) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:11.0.0-M1]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:11.0.0-M1]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:328) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:11.0.0-M1]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:271) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:11.0.0-M1]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:234) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:11.0.0-M1]
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-11.0.0-M1.jar!/:11.0.0-M1]
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-11.0.0-M1.jar!/:11.0.0-M1]
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-11.0.0-M1.jar!/:11.0.0-M1]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> 43 common frames omitted
> 2023-01-10T12:40:42.615Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:252) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]`
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar!/:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar!/:3.0.1]

What can i do?

I tried changing it to war and it deploys sucessfully to docker image but it doesnt work for AWS and railway.app or any other cloud.

And general question, somehow related to this one:

How can i deploy my app in other way which is good-practice for the future? I mean should I maybe try other way than deploying it to cloud, for example running it on my PC and then changing some ports in my router?

I want my app to be visible in public domain.

I also have Raspberry Pi so it could be my server.

Comment: Do you put Spring Boot war to Standalone Tomcat ?

Comment: If You packaging Spring Boot war for Stand alone Tomcat, You need add `<scope>provided</scope>` , For `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-XXXX</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Spring Boot 3.x need  run with JDK 17.

Comment: here is how i do it:
````<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   <version>11.0.0-M1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>````

I run it with JDK 17

Comment: I think its same as yours?

Comment: Do you put war in standalone tomcat ? or Run it like `java -jar xxxx.war`?

Comment: Can you show you pom.xml ?

Comment: i tried to run it with java -jar xxxx.war when i deployed it to railway.app

I dont know how does AWS do it, but i just uploaded war to elastic beanstalk (i think its the same way as you writted)

Comment: https://justpaste.it/bbig4

here is my pom bro

Comment: Your original Question, how do you run your spring boot web application ? (1) Run in Standalone Tomcat server (2) Run `java -jar xxx.war` (3) or others ?

Comment: (1) If you want to use `java -jar xxxx.war` , change your Spring Boot version to 2.7.6, do not use Spring Boot 3.x. (2) And it is no need to add `version`.(For tomcat-embed-XXXX) (3) if you want to 
 use  `java -jar xxxx.war` , Remove `<scope>provided</scope>`

Comment: I used ````import jakarta.persistence.*;```` to mark annotations such as @Entity or @Table and it does not work now. Do you know what to do?

Comment: After change to Spring Boot version 2.7.6 ?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.7.6 use javax.xxxx; Spring Boot 3.x use jakarta.xxxx;

Comment: You can create a Spring Boot app and deploy it to a container using AWS Fargate. I have done this successfully and it works fine. If you are not familiar with AWS Fargate, I suggest reading the AWS Fargate docs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076547/failed-to-start-webserverstartstop-spring-boot-app