# Failed to start 'webServerStartStop' spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, servlets, webserver

After trying to run my app which main Class is present here:

```
@SpringBootApplication public class RappersInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

SpringApplication.run(RappersInfo.class, args);

    }   @Component
    public class JspContextCustomizer implements TomcatContextCustomizer {
        @Override
        public void customize(Context context) {
            JspPropertyGroup group = new JspPropertyGroup();
            group.addUrlPattern("/*");
            group.setPageEncoding("UTF-8");
            context.setJspConfigDescriptor(new JspConfigDescriptorImpl(
                    Collections.singletonList(new JspPropertyGroupDescriptorImpl(group)),
                    Collections.emptyList()));
        }
    }
}
```

I get that error after trying to run that class:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
> at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at com.example.RappersInfo.demo.RappersInfo.main(RappersInfo.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
> 19 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Servlet [jsp] in web application [] threw load() exception
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:3215) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.lambda$deferredLoadOnStartup$0(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.doWithThreadContextClassLoader(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:105) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.performDeferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatWebServer.java:305) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:216) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> 21 common frames omitted
> Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Class [org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet] is not a Servlet
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1072) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1007) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:81) ~[spring-boot-2.7.6.jar:2.7.6]
> 37 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Servlet (org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet and javax.servlet.Servlet are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1067) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
> 39 common frames omitted

And here is my pom.xml:

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.RappersInfo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rappersInfoImage</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-jstl</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>```


 What can i do?

Tried almost everything what was in the internet.

Error happens after changing spring boot version from 3.x. to 2.7.6 (i want to deploy it with war file). Im not sure about my pom.xml. Maybe there is a problem with tomcat dependencies?
````

Answer (score -1):

A similar error occurs if your address or port is incorrect / already used. This fixes the error in most situations, but a driver like the one mentioned above may cause the error.

Try changing port number from `8080` to something else. If that doesn't suffice, then one other instance I came across is as the following :

There was control software installed for the individuals Network interface controller (NIC) that allowed both ethernet and wifi to be used simultaneously. This was installed to supposedly improve gaming experience, but did not play nicely with tomcat in Spring. Once disabled the application was able to run as expected. It is described as follows :

This was a network interface Carr driver for an installed card. It will be different depending on card and driver installed - You can look at your drivers by looking at the Device Manager on windows.

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score -1):

There was control software installed for the individuals Network interface controller (NIC) that allowed both ethernet and wifi to be used simultaneously. This was installed to supposedly improve gaming experience, but did not play nicely with tomcat in Spring. Once disabled the application was able to run as expected.

A similar error occurs if your address or port is incorrect / already used. This fixes the error in most situations, but a driver like the one mentioned above may cause the error.

Disable the Gamingservices service or go to the task manager and end the task of gamingservices and run again the application. or restart the computer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTi4s.png)